Error In pagination rule in ADF REST API Activity
Hi All I am new to this ADF pipeline and would need your help in how to set up pagination rule.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support
I followed the above url to add the pagination rule. My REST Api supports pagination using query parameter like $skip , $top ,$inlinecount.
For first page with 100 records i can set-up like this  $skip =0 and $top=100 and with $inlinecount=allpages in url it returns me total no of rows.
I am using COPY Activity and using REST endpoint as source, and having difficulty in setting up the pagination rule.
I tried to set up the relative url like this

and pagination rule like for skip parameter first.

But getting following error

Any help how to set up the queryparameter for top and skip and end of pagination would really help

Queryparameter value also set as {skip}

In pagination Queryparameter variable Use curly braces as you added in your relative  url.
My sample Rest Api:

In Pagination rule variable as it is:

For you add {skip},{top}in your queryparameter variable.
